# Привязка дочернего окон к родительскому окну

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qstackedlayout

Мне нужно чтобы после нажатия **`ПКМ`** дополнительное окно фиксировалось по отношению к родительскому и при перетягивании родительского окна в другое место, дополнительное окно следовало за родительским.

А также как я могу реализовать передвижение родительского окна?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который есть сейчас:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(QSize(230, 65))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.position()
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
                self.QtStack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
                self.stack1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
                self.Window1UI()
                self.QtStack.addWidget(self.stack1)
                self.QtStack.setParent(self.stack1)

    # Дополнительное окно
    def Window1UI(self):
        self.stack1.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.stack1.resize(QSize(230, 195))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPosition()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPointF(event.globalPosition() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPosition()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: ваше изображение сбивает с толку. Что такое 'Дополнительное окно 2' ? откуда оно берется ?

Comment: @S.Nick оно вызывается после нажатия ПКМ "if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:"

Comment: а почему на изображении стрелку на 'доп.окно 2' идет от 'доп.окна' ?

Answer (score 2):

Я обратил внимание, что вы используете `QStackedLayout`
и наполнил его функционалом.

Класс **`QStackedLayout`** предоставляет стек виджетов,
в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

Вы можете пользоваться **`ЛКМ`** и **`ПКМ`** в '**`Родительском окне`**',
а также переключать дополнительные виджеты кнопкой.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

        
class Main(QMainWindow):                     
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.w, self.h = 230, 65
        self.delta_x, self.delta_y = 0, 20
        
        self.resize(QSize(self.w, self.h))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'Родительское окно', 
            self, 
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(165, 65, 65);")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)

        self.main_widget = QWidget()                       # <---- !!!
        self.main_widget.resize(220, 180)
        self.stack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()            # <---- !!!
        self.btn = QPushButton("Change window")        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_window)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        layout.addLayout(self.stack)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.pos_main)
        self.num = 1
        
    def pos_main(self):
        self.main_widget.move(
            self.pos() + QPoint(self.delta_x, self.h+self.delta_y)
        )

    def change_window(self):
        currentIndex = self.stack.currentIndex()
        stackCount = self.stack.count()
        if currentIndex == stackCount - 1:
            currentIndex = 0
        else:
            currentIndex += 1
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(currentIndex)

    # +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
            stack1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            widget = self.window1UI(stack1)
            self.stack.addWidget(widget)
            self.stack.setCurrentIndex(self.stack.count()-1)
            self.main_widget.show()
            
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
            self.main_widget.move(self.main_widget.pos() + delta)
    # +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def window1UI(self, stack1):
        stack1.move(self.pos() + QPoint(self.delta_x, self.h+self.delta_y))
        label = QLabel(
            f"In Window <span style='color: red;'>{self.num}</span>", 
            stack1
        )
        self.num += 1
        return stack1

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @МаркСимпл что не так ?